# Can not execute restart networking service on Ubuntu 14.04

Tags: ubuntu

I use `Ubuntu 14.04 LTS`, I try type `sudo /etc.init.d/networking restart` but no output's displayed and no action excuted.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In `/etc/init.d/networking`, you can see:

```
....
force-reload|restart)
        if init_is_upstart; then
                exit 1
        fi
....
```

And from `/lib/lsb/init-functions`:

```
# If the currently running init daemon is upstart, return zero; if the
# calling init script belongs to a package which also provides a native
# upstart job, it should generally exit non-zero in this case.
init_is_upstart()
{
   if [ -x /sbin/initctl ] && /sbin/initctl version 2>/dev/null | /bin/grep -q upstart; then
       return 0
   fi
   return 1
}
```

`Ubuntu 14.04` distro uses `upstart` as its `init daemon`, so when you run `/etc/init.d/networking restart`, it checks the currently running `init daemon` is `upstart` or not. If it is `upstart`, then it simply exits the script.

**Note**

In my `Ubuntu 12.04`, there is no `init_is_upstart` in `/etc/lsb/init-functions`. Maybe it have been added in newer version of `Ubuntu`.

Answer (score 4):

I remember reading somewhere that using `sudo /etc/init.d/networking restart` is no longer supported as of 14.04. You could try running `sudo ifdown eth0` followed by `sudo ifup eth0`. Of course you need to replace 'eth0' with whatever interface you need restarted. This should accomplish the same as using the init script.

I found a github repo with a replacement networking script for Ubuntu 14.04 that should make `sudo service networking restart` work as it did with 13.10. I have not tried the script, but it might be worth looking into.

https://github.com/metral/restore_networking

Comment: `service network-manager restart` works for me in Ubuntu 14.04